# How prompt=login and prompt=none works in OpenAM-6.5.2

Tags: openid-connect, openam

I am working on OpenAM-6.5.2 and wish to understand how `prompt=none` and `prompt=login` works in `oauth-2.0/OpenID-connect`.

Also when to use which parameter in OpenID-Connect flows and what is the significance of it.

I understand that flow will start from authorise flow (as using Authorisation code flow)
Can anyone please elaborate more on this ?

Answer (score 1):

By default in OIDC you do not specify a `prompt` parameter. It can be useful in some cases to force a new login after a `logout with issues`. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/logout/) describes an iOS example.

The older single page apps flow used `prompt=none` as a mechanism to renew access tokens, as described in [this post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/). These days this flow has reliability issues though, due to nore recent browser restrictions on third party cookies.

I do not know about the OpenAM system though - always possible there is some vendor specific behaviour that works in a custom way.

Comment: OIDC should not be  used to renew access tokens. It is meant for id tokens ideally.